# Newest Android Studio 2021.3.1.17 release gets stuck on launch screen

Tags: android-studio

I've installed the newest version of Android Studio with the installer on my Windows 10, currently it's version 2021.3.1.17 Dolphin.

Upon launching it, the splash screen appears and the little bar loads to the end and then it gets stuck indefinitely on that screen. All I'm seeing is this: [image: splash screen of android studio dolphin]

I've tried the following stuff already:

- Completely uninstalling Android Studio, making sure all the files have been removed correctly before re-installing it (except the JetBrains folder, since I have other JetBrains stuff in it)
- Re-Downloading the installer from the official Android Studio Website to make sure it was not corrupted.
- Run as Administrator.
- Was previously installed on a non-primary drive D:/, and I've also tried installing it on my primary drive C:/ just in case, same issue with C:/ installation too.
- Ran studio.bat to see any errors, however, I'm assuming that bat file itself is buggy. It tells me that it does not find any JRE or JDK installation within the path. So to fix it I've set the newest Oracle JDK19 as my JAVA_HOME and the /bin accordingly, however, the studio.bat will then continue a long java error which seems honestly unfixable, so I won't even bother posting it here. Me setting the path shouldn't even be necessary, as Android Studio comes bundled with a JDK... and it should be using that one anyway.

So I'm out of things to try. I cannot make it work. My only lead was the Java error, but according to some Google search, I shouldn't even have to deal with it as it comes bundled with Android Studio. Looking into the files, there is indeed a jre folder within the Android Studio installation. Is it not using that one? What could be the reason that it is not using it if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to fix it myself after trying a few hours more. I've had also other Java installations (Java JDK 8, JDK 19) that interfered somehow with Android Studio. I've uninstalled everything related to Android Studio and I've uninstalled every Java version I had.

Additionally, I've removed every reference to Java or Android Studio from all of my system and environment variables. Also removed a path to Android SDK that was within my system variables.

After rebooting and installing Android Studio, it worked. Haven't installed any Java version so far, so not sure if the issues will return if I install my Java versions again.